# How to restart bot and save background tasks

Tags: python, discord.py, restart, background-task

I'm making a discord bot in python and I want to restart my bot every day to update it.

All my code works (it pull the code from GitHub) but when I restart the bot, all the background tasks (as the `bot.wait_for`) are lost. I tried to find a solution on Google without success.

Is there any solution for this problem?

P.S. I can put the code here but I'm not sure if it would help.

Comment: It is really difficult to resume a process like that, my suggestion would be to use a process manager like `Docker` and simply pause the process when necessary (without actually restarting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid that I generally work with Cogs and I have enable and disable cogs(more generally known as load and unload) which actually help in restarting certain Cogs(basically certain parts of code) instead of the whole code.

You can learn more about Cogs by reading the Discord.py [Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html).

Learn more about Unloading a Cog [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html).

Hope it helped!! Feel free to comment if you have some more queries.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I also use Cogs an your solution is for now the best aside part that with this solution i can't reload a cog if there is at the moment a ```bot.wait_for``` in the cog targeted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use crontab linux command to schedule your task periodically. Let me notice it this could work for you

https://stackabuse.com/scheduling-jobs-with-python-crontab

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but this does not answer my question because when I restart the bot to apply the changes, all the background tasks (as the wait_for reactions) will be lost. Is there another way?